# selecting Node does not work using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using VS2010 and using HTMLAGilityPack1.4.6 (from Net40-folder).
Following is my HTML

```
<html>

<body>


<div id="header">

<h2 id="hd1">
    Patient Name
</h2>   
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

I am using following code in C# to access "hd1".
Please tell me correct way to do it.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
try
{
    string filePath = "E:\\file1.htm";
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(filePath);

    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    { 

        HtmlNodeCollection _hdPatient = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@id=hd1]");
        // htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@id='hd1']");  
        //_hdPatient.InnerHtml = "Patient SurName";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Tried many permutations and combinations... I get null.

plz help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the way how you load data into `HtmlDocument`. In order to load data from file you should use `Load(fileName)` method. But you are using `LoadHtml(htmlString)` method, which treats `"E:\\file1.htm"` as document content. When HtmlAgilityPack tries to find `h2` tags in `E:\\file1.htm` string, it finds nothing. Here is the correct way to load html file:

```
string filePath = "E:\\file1.htm";
htmlDoc.Load(filePath); // use instead of LoadHtml
```

---

Also @Simon Mourier correctly pointed that you should use `SelectSingleNode` method if you are trying to get single node:

```
// Single HtmlNode
var patient = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2[@id='hd1'");
patient.InnerHtml = "Patient SurName";
```

Or if you are working with collection of nodes, then process them in a loop:

```
// Collection of nodes
var patients = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='patient'");
foreach (var patient in patients)
    patient.SetAttributeValue("style", "visibility: hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
HtmlNode _hdPatient = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2[@id='hd1']");
_hdPatient.InnerHtml = "Patient SurName"
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - not exactly

Comment: @ErikSchierboom nope, difference is the `SelectSingleNode` method. But that is not core problem of OP