# Iterate through html elements using htmlagilitypack does not work

Tags: asp.net

I need some help please as I can't develope a parser using htmlagilitypack.

I've a div with some sub-div each containing a link to a side.
eg.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
    <div>some content</div>
    <div class="project-categories" itemprop="occupationalCategory">
        <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="1.htm">1</a></div>
        <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="2.htm7">2</a></div>
        <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="3.htm">3</a></div>          
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I set XPath to I like to Iterate through:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"test\"]/div[2]"))
 {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
 }
```

The result is always the same I get only one node containing the whole innerHtml of the XPath.

```
    <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="1.htm">1</a></div>
    <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="2.htm7">2</a></div>
    <div class="cat_object"><a class="cat_child" target="_self" href="3.htm">3</a></div>
```

I did some search and found a couple of useful examples eg.
[selecting Node does not work using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042835/selecting-node-does-not-work-using-htmlagilitypack)

But what ever I try - the problem still remains.

Can you help me please to access the items to get each one in a single node?

Thank you!
Andre

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.
There's additional /div missing so

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"test\"]/div[2]/div"))
```

works fine.